# Dual booting Windows 10 and Linux(Parrot Sec OS) UEFI GRUB NOT LOADING

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, uefi

I've partitioned my hard drive and installed `Parrot Security OS` to the new partition. It completed without errors. However, when i rebooted after installation, my laptop (ACER E5-575G- Laptop) booted straight into windows without loading `GRUB`. I've tried installing `efibootmgr` on the Parrot OS `live boot` and changing the boot order, so that it boots to Parrot OS first. This didn't work. Then i tried to change the boot order in the `UEFI` menu. I changed it so that it boots to the `GRUB.efi` from `Parrot OS`. This didn't work either. I've also disabled fast boot and secure boot and tried with them enabled as well.

What should I do?